# Linux bash: /usr/lib/command-not-found: /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or director

Tags: python, linux, bash

I'm very new to Linux and have stupidly messed around with the version of python installed. Now, when I try to install docker for the first time, I get this error:

```
$ curl -fsSL get.docker.com -o get-docker.sh
bash: /usr/lib/command-not-found: /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or director*
```

Trying to fix the problem I have scrabbled across the web, copying and pasting fixes that haven't actually worked, and I think have probably made the situation worse.

If anyone could help me fixing the solution, I would be so grateful!

```
~$ python --version
Python 2.7.17

~$ which python
/usr/bin/python

~$ ls -l /usr/bin/python*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 Apr 16  2018 /usr/bin/python -> python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 Apr 16  2018 /usr/bin/python2 -> python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3637096 Apr 15 18:20 /usr/bin/python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      18 Jun  8 14:31 /usr/bin/python3 -> /usr/bin/python3.5
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4526456 Apr 18 02:56 /usr/bin/python3.6
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4526456 Apr 18 02:56 /usr/bin/python3.6m
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      10 Apr  3 01:00 /usr/bin/python3m -> python3.6m
```

Comment: This looks like `curl` is not installed, so when the shell can't find `curl` to execute, your distribution tries to invoke a pre-defined `command_not_found_handle` function which calls `/usr/lib/command-not-found`. This command, though, starts with a shebang like `#!/usr/bin/python3`, and you may have uninstalled `/usr/bin/python3.5`.

Comment: `python3` links to `python3.5` which doesn't exist. Redirect it to `python3.6`, which will probably do the job. However, there may be more proper ways but those depend on your OS. Actually, I'd even consider it a bug when the system is messed up like that, provided you didn't mess it up manually. That said, take the [tour] and read [ask], because this is not really a programming question and perhaps better off at e.g. superuser.com.

Comment: Yes whoops, thank you!

Comment: What OS are you using and what version? If it's Ubuntu 18.04, then yeah, simply relinking `/usr/bin/python3 -> python3.6` will work.